# Replacing a string in one file, with the contents of another file based on a common string

Tags: awk, sed

I have two files. I would like to replace a certain string in file 1, with the contents of file 2 based on a common string.

file 1

```
   Chr5 psl2gff exon    15907715    15907933    .   +   .   NM_001046410
   Chr2 psl2gff exon    8898358     8898394     .   +   .   NM_001192190
```

file 2

```
NM_001046410 gene_id TUBA1D; transcript_id tubulin, alpha 3d
NM_001192190 gene_id BOD1L1; transcript_id biorientation of chromosomes in cell division 1 like 1
```

output

```
  Chr5  psl2gff exon    15907715    15907933    .   +   .   gene_id TUBA1D; transcript_id tubulin, alpha 3d
  Chr2  psl2gff exon    8898358     8898394     .   +   .   gene_id BOD1L1; transcript_id biorientation of chromosomes in cell division 1 like 1
```

in file 1 there are multiple instances of the same string, however, file 2 only has it once. I would like all instances of the NM_**** etc. to be replaced by the contents of file 2 when the first column matches. following this, I would like to completely remove the NM_**** from the file.

I am very new to bash etc. I have looked all over the place for a way to do this, but none so far have worked. Also, there are over 5000 lines in file 2, many more in file 1.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in you post too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 FYI I see [your question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372529/1745001) about the jww-effect got closed as a dup of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255459/1745001 so I added a comment to that just to counter jww's claim there that his behavior is acceptable. Nothing is going to come of this though so I'm not going to put any more energy into it.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure thanks Ed sir for support, totally discouraged as of now got lot of beatings :(

Comment: yeah it's funny how SO purports to be a friendly site and you ask one question in Meta and get absolutely destroyed :-). Happened to me the one time I posted a question there too - it's a clique.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Thought you'd find this interesting - someone created a tool at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/890812 where you can tell which posts jww commented on that you were involved with so you can tell when you get downvoted that he was involved! Of course it can't tell you about the cases where he just downvoted everyone without commenting but it is interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a `join` operation.  If the files are sorted on the join key, and if the white space is not significant the easiest will be

```
$ join -19 -21 file1 file2 | cut -d' ' -f2-

Chr5 psl2gff exon 15907715 15907933 . + . gene_id TUBA1D; transcript_id tubulin, alpha 3d
Chr2 psl2gff exon 8898358 8898394 . + . gene_id BOD1L1; transcript_id biorientation of chromosomes in cell division 1 like 1
```

if the files are not sorted and white space is important `awk` will be a better solution

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR  {k=$1; $1=""; a[k]=$0; next} 
       $NF in a {sub(FS $NF"$",a[$NF])}1' file2 file1 

   Chr5 psl2gff exon    15907715    15907933    .   +   .  gene_id TUBA1D; transcript_id tubulin, alpha 3d
   Chr2 psl2gff exon    8898358     8898394     .   +   .  gene_id BOD1L1; transcript_id biorientation of chromosomes in cell division 1 like 1
```

exercise for you is to understand the code.  There are many examples (>100) on this site exactly for this question and with many commented scripts, some of which are written by me.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to use similar code found here and other places, I just cant seem to get them to work. I'll try to work on with this awk command you have posted. You're right, I do have to understand it - which is something I do not.

Comment: you can always ask a particular part of the script if it seems to hard to understand, but most of it is trivial once you know what each keyword means...

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. It turns out the formating of my document required work a quick column -t file1, followed by your command worked wonders.